# Can't convert setState to BloC

Tags: flutter, state-management, flutter-bloc

I am developing an audio player application using Flutter, I am using [on_audio_query package](https://pub.dev/packages/on_audio_query) to get audio files from device storage, and [just_audio package](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio) for the audio player.

when I created the project, in the audio player I used setState to handle state management, and now, I want to convert to [bloc pattern](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc) but when I tried to do that I faced a lot of issues and couldn't fix them.

I will attach the code of the audio player and also basic cubit code and if someone guided me or showed me how to convert I would appreciate it.

I'm sorry if the code is confusing but I don't know how to add it correctly.

**audio player code**

```
import 'package:just_audio/just_audio.dart';
import 'package:dorosi/shared/ui/my_icon.dart';
import 'package:dorosi/shared/ui/my_text.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:on_audio_query/on_audio_query.dart';

class AudioPlayerWithUrl extends StatefulWidget {
  final SongModel songModel;

  const AudioPlayerWithUrl({required this.songModel, Key? key})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AudioPlayerWithUrl> createState() => _AudioPlayerWithUrlState();
}

class _AudioPlayerWithUrlState extends State<AudioPlayerWithUrl> {
  final audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
  bool isPlaying = false;
  Duration duration = const Duration();
  Duration position = const Duration();
  bool isPressed = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    setAudio();
    playAudio();
  }

  Future setAudio() async {
    audioPlayer.setLoopMode(LoopMode.off);
    audioPlayer.setAudioSource(
      AudioSource.uri(
        Uri.parse(widget.songModel.uri!),
      ),
    );
    isPlaying = true;

audioPlayer.durationStream.listen((audioDuration) {
  setState(() {
    duration = audioDuration!;
  });
});

audioPlayer.positionStream.listen((audioPosition) {
  setState(() {
    position = audioPosition;
  });
});
```

}

```
  @override
  void dispose() {
    audioPlayer.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const MyText(
          writtenText: 'Now Playing',
          textSize: 23,
          textColor: Colors.black,
        ),
        leading: IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
            icon: const MyIcon(
              icon: Icons.arrow_back,
              iconColor: Colors.black,
            )),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0,
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            icon: const MyIcon(
              icon: Icons.more_vert,
              iconColor: Colors.black,
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(width: 10)
        ],
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            const SizedBox(height: 15),
            const CircleAvatar(
              backgroundColor: Color(0xFFc61104),
              radius: 100,
              child: MyIcon(
                icon: Icons.music_note,
                iconSize: 100,
                iconColor: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 15,
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 15),
            MyText(
              writtenText: widget.songModel.title,
              textSize: 24,
              textWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 4),
            MyText(
              writtenText: widget.songModel.album!,
              textSize: 20,
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 10),
            Slider(
                activeColor: Colors.orange,
                inactiveColor: Colors.black87,
                min: 0,
                max: duration.inSeconds.toDouble(),
                value: position.inSeconds.toDouble(),
                onChanged: (value) async {
                  isPlaying = true;
                  final position = Duration(seconds: value.toInt());
                  await audioPlayer.seek(position);
                  await audioPlayer.play();
                }),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  MyText(
                      writtenText: formatTime(position),
                      textWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  TextButton(
                    style: TextButton.styleFrom(primary: Colors.black),
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        showRemainingTime();
                        isPressed = !isPressed;
                      });
                    },
                    child: isPressed
                        ? showRemainingTime()
                        : MyText(
                            writtenText: ' ${formatTime(duration)}',
                            textWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFc61104),
                  radius: 23,
                  child: IconButton(
                      onPressed: () async {
                        if (position >= const Duration(seconds: 10)) {
                          seekTo(position.inSeconds - 10);
                        } else {
                          setState(() {
                            seekTo(const Duration(seconds: 0).inSeconds);
                            isPlaying = false;
                          });
                          pauseAudio();
                        }
                      },
                      icon: const MyIcon(
                        icon: Icons.settings_backup_restore,
                        iconSize: 30,
                        iconColor: Colors.white,
                      )),
                ),
                const SizedBox(width: 40),
                CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFc61104),
                  radius: 35,
                  child: IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(
                      isPlaying ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    iconSize: 50,
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        if (isPlaying) {
                          pauseAudio();
                        } else {
                          playAudio();
                        }
                        isPlaying = !isPlaying;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(width: 40),
                CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 23,
                  backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFc61104),
                  child: IconButton(
                      onPressed: () async {
                        if (position < duration - const Duration(seconds: 10)) {
                          seekTo(position.inSeconds + 10);
                        } else {
                          setState(() {
                            seekTo(duration.inSeconds);
                            isPlaying = false;
                          });
                          pauseAudio();
                        }
                  },
                  icon: const MyIcon(
                    icon: Icons.forward_10,
                    iconSize: 30,
                    iconColor: Colors.white,
                  )),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 15),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
           
            const SizedBox(width: 40),
            ElevatedButton(
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(primary: Colors.orange),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    if (audioPlayer.speed == 1) {
                      adjustAudioSpeed();
                      debugPrint('${audioPlayer.speed}');
                    } else if (audioPlayer.speed == 1.25) {
                      adjustAudioSpeed2();
                    } else if (audioPlayer.speed == 1.5) {
                      adjustAudioSpeed3();
                    } else if (audioPlayer.speed == 1.75) {
                      adjustAudioSpeed4();
                    } else if (audioPlayer.speed == 2) {
                      setAudioNormalSpeed();
                    }
                  });
                },
                child: MyText(
                  writtenText: '${audioPlayer.speed}',
                  textSize: 18,
                  textColor: Colors.black,
                )),
            const SizedBox(width: 40),
          
          ],
        )
      ],
    ),
  )),
);
```

}

```
  Widget showRemainingTime() {
    return MyText(
      writtenText: '- ${formatTime(duration - position)}',
      textWeight: FontWeight.bold,
    );
  }

  seekTo(int seconds) {
    audioPlayer.seek(Duration(seconds: seconds));
  }

  playAudio() {
    audioPlayer.play();
  }

  pauseAudio() {
    audioPlayer.pause();
  }

  setAudioNormalSpeed() {
    audioPlayer.setSpeed(1);
  }

  adjustAudioSpeed() {
    audioPlayer.setSpeed(1.25);
  }

  adjustAudioSpeed2() {
    audioPlayer.setSpeed(1.5);
  }

  adjustAudioSpeed3() {
    audioPlayer.setSpeed(1.75);
  }

  adjustAudioSpeed4() {
    audioPlayer.setSpeed(2);
  }

  playNextAudio() {
    audioPlayer.seekToNext();
  }

  playPreviousAudio() {
    audioPlayer.seekToPrevious();
  }
  String formatTime(Duration duration) {
    String twoDigits(int n) => n.toString().padLeft(2, '0');
    final hours = twoDigits(duration.inHours);
    final minutes = twoDigits(duration.inMinutes.remainder(60));
    final seconds = twoDigits(duration.inSeconds.remainder(60));

    return [
      if (duration.inHours > 0) hours,
      minutes,
      seconds,
    ].join(':');
  }
}
```

**player cubit code**

```
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';

part 'player_state.dart';

class PlayerCubit extends Cubit<PlayerState> {
  static PlayerCubit get(context) => BlocProvider.of(context);

  PlayerCubit() : super(PlayerInitialState());
}
```

**player state code**

```
part of 'player_cubit.dart';

@immutable
abstract class PlayerState {}

class PlayerInitialState extends PlayerState {}

class PlayerPlayingState extends PlayerState {}

class PlayerPauseState extends PlayerState {}
```

Comment: Would be much easier to help you if you pointed out exactly what problems you have with translation it into bloc.